# Variable declaration / notation

Tags: powershell, variables

I would like to know how variables are declared in the PowerShell scripting language.

There is a clear definition for this in other programming and scripting languages. Unfortunately, I couldn't find it for PowerShell.

**Are PowerShell variables declared as Upper Case, Lower Case, or in Camel Case notation?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know how variables are declared

### They are not!

In PowerShell, variables are non-typed (ie. they can contain *anything*), and they are implicitly created in the local scope on assignment:

```bsh
PS C:\> Get-Variable abc # nothing returned
PS C:\> $abc = "somevalue"
PS C:\> Get-Variable abc

Name                           Value
----                           -----
abc                            somevalue
```

Declaration ahead of time is therefore not necessary in PowerShell.

The only exception is variables used to declare *parameters*

---

> **Are PowerShell variables declared as Upper Case, Lower Case, or in Camel Case notation?**

There's no hard an fast rule here, but a common practice is:

- `$camelCase` for local variable names
- `$PascalCase` for parameter names

Example function:

```bsh
function Get-RandomValue
{
  param(
    [string]$ValuePrefix
  )

  $randomValue = Get-Random

  return $ValuePrefix + $randomValue
}
```

Although I'd *recommend* sticking to this convention, it is not strictly required.

---

As [iRon notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64479757/variable-declaration-notation/64480042?noredirect=1#comment114016732_64480042), this is not just my personal preference, it's shared by the authors of the [PowerShell Practice and Style Guide](https://poshcode.gitbooks.io/powershell-practice-and-style/content/Style-Guide/Code-Layout-and-Formatting.html) - of which the chapter on naming conventions (not just for variables) is definitely worth a read!

Comment: @iRon thanks, I'd all but forgotten about that guide! Answer updated